# In Android, Is Two way Data binding is optimize for Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I am working on data binding in android and implement list of User name with Recycler View.
I have question that when I change name of particular user in the list, is every time RecyclerView's adapter notified internally.

```
 public class UserModel extends BaseObservable {
 private String name;

 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }

@Bindable
public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
     notifyChange();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is enough to get views bound to `name` in the `RecyclerView`'s item to update but if you need the `LayoutManager` to redo the layout (e.g. if the name change causes the item size to change), you must explicitly call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter.